# How to output a large number of histograms in a pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

`df` is a dataframe with a days column. There are 100 days. I want to look at a histogram for my data column for each of the 100 days. The problem is that this code outputs everything on a single chart and all histograms are stacked together. Two questions:

1. Any advice to get one histogram for each day?
2. Any advice to save each histogram to an appropriately named file?

*Note: When I replace `hist` in my code below with `describe`, it perfectly gives me 100 describe series. Also, the type of the `grouper.get_group(days)` object is `pandas.series`.*

My simple code:

```
grouper = df.groupby('days')['data']

for days in grouper.groups.keys():
    print grouper.get_group(days).hist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use inline plotting either in `ipython qtconsole` or `ipython notebook`:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for days in grouper.groups.keys():
    grouper.get_group(days).hist()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: as a bonus, I have replaced the `plt.show()` line with `plt.savefig('name of my choice %s.png' % days`) and it shows me a stacked histogram, where it includes one more day's worth of stacked histogram as the days go on.... How do I save each histogram? I was assuming `savefig` would do the trick but it doesn't.

Comment: you might need to "reset the plot" each time through the loop, maybe adding in `ax=plt.axes()` at the start of each loop will do the trick?

Answer (score -1):

Actually, if you are using the Ipython notebook, you can simply do:

```
df.groupby('days')['data'].hist()
```

Any function added to the end of the groupby will be fired for all groups in parallel, this is the strength of the groupby function.

No need to iterate

Comment: doesn't work. I get a single stacked histogram of everything with one color per day... not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @user3659451 I must have missunderstood what you want. Maybe you can add some picture examples to your question that shows what you are after?

Comment: If you ever run into a similar situation try the difference between the two answers. They are different in the way I described.