# Adding color to Histograms displayed by group

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

There was a [question I asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714787/how-to-output-a-large-number-of-histograms-in-a-pandas-groupby/31718243#31718243), and here is a more specific follow-up question:

`df` is a dataframe with a `days, data, binary` column. There are 100 days. I want to look at a histogram for my `data` column for each of the 100 days where `binary` is shown by color (say *red* is 0 and *blue* is 1).  **How do I do this?**

The nuanced addition is the addition of the `binary` column.

Current code looks like (this is in IPython Notebook):

```
n_groups = lambda x: len(grouper.groups[x])
for days in grouper.groups.keys():
    current_num_groups = n_groups(days)
    grouper.get_group(days).hist()
    plt.suptitle("Days: {}".format(days))
    plt.xlabel('Data, Count: {}'.format(current_num_groups))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Unless I am not understanding things correctly, why not split the data into two:  data0 and data1, where data0 corresponds to binary = 0, and data1 where binary = 1, and then plot the histogram via:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html

Comment: So I would have to make a function to split each group's dataframe into those two dataframes... hm I'll give it a shot. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, the one-line Python way to do this is as follows:
data0 = df.loc[ df["binary"] == 0]

Comment: There is [this more recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56638467/how-to-fill-color-by-groups-in-histogram-using-matplotlib) that contains a couple of answers showing how to solve this problem.