# How to fill color by groups in histogram using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, histogram, data-visualization

I know how to do this in R and have provided a code for it below. I want to know how can I do something similar to the below mentioned in Python Matplotlib or using any other library

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dia[1:768,], aes(x = Glucose, fill = Outcome)) +
  geom_bar() +
  ggtitle("Glucose") +
  xlab("Glucose") +
  ylab("Total Count") +
  labs(fill = "Outcome")
```

[image]

Comment: http://ggplot.yhathq.com/

Comment: I think `ggplot` is old and no longer maintained. One replacement is [plotnine](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 5):

Using pandas you can pivot the dataframe and directly plot it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dataframe with two columns in "long form"
g = np.array([np.random.normal(5, 10, 500),
              np.random.rayleigh(10, size=500)]).flatten()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Glucose': g, 'Outcome': np.repeat([0,1],500)})

# pivot and plot
df.pivot(columns="Outcome", values="Glucose").plot.hist(bins=100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you pick the colors?

Comment: @Ryan probably figured it out but for anyone else wondering, you can provide a list of colors to `plot.hist()` via the `color` argument. Also, note that you can use the `stacked=True` argument so the histograms don't overlap. It defaults to False.

Comment: @ImportanceofBeingErnest, why when I do random_sample_join.pivot(columns="p_pb6", values = [x for x in random_sample_join]).hist(bins = 5, figsize = (30,30))
plt.show() does it still give me a separate graph for every pandas value in p_pb6 for every variable I am plotting rather then color coding based on that variable like in your output?

Answer (score 4):

Please consider the following example, which uses [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) 0.11.1.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate random data
data = {'Glucose': np.random.normal(5, 10, 100),
        'Outcome': np.random.randint(2, size=100)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
sns.histplot(data=df, x='Glucose', hue='Outcome', stat='count', edgecolor=None)
ax.set_title('Glucose')
```